# jQuery set flag to stop submit loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a bit of a logic error that I need help with. The code works great, I'm just not sure where to set my flag to stop an infinite loop.

There is a login page where I first `preventDefault` then pull data from the form, process the data, replace some data and then `submit` the form myself with the new data. The issue is, is that when I submit the form my function starts over and goes into an infinite loop. I know I need to set a flag, I'm just not sure where. Here is my current code WITH the infinite loop.

```
var flag = false;
$(function() {
if(flag != true){
  $("form[action='account/login']").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    custEmail = $("form[action='account/login'] input[type=email]").val();
      if(products.length != 0){
          $.ajax({
              url: "/apps/proxy/customer",
              data: {custEmail, products},
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
              complete: function(data) {
                $("form[action='account/login'], input[name='checkout_url']").attr("value", data.responseText);
                form = $("form[action='account/login']");
                var flag = true;
                form.submit();
              },
          });           
      }
  });
 }
});
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a flag, you need to trigger the **native** submit handler, not jQuery's submit handler, which would just throw you into a infinite loop and never submit the form.

```
$(function() {
    $("form[action='account/login']").on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var form      = this;
        var custEmail = $("input[type=email]", form).val();

        if (products.length != 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/apps/proxy/customer",
                data: {
                    custEmail,
                    products
                },
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json"
            }).done(function(data) {
                $("input[name='checkout_url']", form).val(data.responseText);
                form.submit();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With the line

`var flag = true`

you're re-declaring the variable flag (because of the 'var' keyword), thus not changing the original one. You need to change that line to just

`flag = true`.